# How to Add features to your website that are from another website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, web-development-server

I am making a website on a twitch streamer, so as twitch shows the top sub giffters and bit donators I want to add that feature to my website also such that when the stats update they also update on my website.

So how do I do this???

Answer (score 0):

Generally on the web, you pull in information from outside sources via web APIs.

It doesn't look like Twitch's API natively does that. I'm not super familiar with Twitch, but I don't believe they natively handle that. If the streamer you are getting information for uses a set service to handle donations, they may have an API that will expose this information.

This is the available information that you can retrieve from Twitch's API: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/channels#get-channel-subscribers

To learn how to make API requests from a web page I would check out some existing tutorials and `fetch`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API